# python IndexError that I cannot resolve with dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a simple problem, and I need a pari of fresh eyes for this. I have a dictionary for my world:

```
world = {}
```

and a function that fills rooms in that dictionary based on a 2d array:

```
def makeRoomsForLevel():

  counter = 1

  for r in range(len(rooms)):
    for c in range(len(rooms)):
      if rooms[c][r] == 1:
        world[f"room{counter}"] = Room(
          f"room{counter}",
          "",
          {},
          False,
          None,
          False,
          None,
          False,
          None,
          True,
          (r, c)
        )
        counter += 1
```

And yet another function that I am working on to find the exits for the room:

```
def findExits():
  counter = 1;

  for x in range(len(world)):
    if rooms[world[f"room{counter}"]].coords[0] + 1 == 1:
      pass
```

I tried running this before I filled in the if statement, and it gave me this error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (':'), ellipsis ('...'), numpy.newaxis ('None') and integer or boolean arrays are valid indicies
```

I kinda know what it means, but it hasn't given me any problems with this before hand.
Here is the room class:

```
class Room():
  def __init__(self, name, description, exits, hasWeapon, weapon, hasItem, item, hasEnemy, enemy, isFirstVisit, coords):
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.exits = exits
    self.hasWeapon = hasWeapon
    self.weapon = weapon
    self.hasItem = hasItem
    self.item = item
    self.hasEnemy = hasEnemy
    self.enemy = enemy
    self.isFirstVisit = isFirstVisit
    self.coords = coords
```

And here is what "rooms" is:

```
rooms = np.zeros((11, 11))
```

Here is the full generation code:

```
rooms = np.zeros((11, 11))
maxRooms = 7
possibleNextRoom = []
world = {}

def startLevel():
  for r in range(len(rooms[0])):
    for c in range(len(rooms[1])):
      rooms[r][c] = 0

  possibleNextRoom.clear()

  halfHeight = int(len(rooms[1]) / 2)
  halfWidth = int(len(rooms[0]) / 2)
  rooms[halfWidth][halfHeight] = 1

def resetLevel():
  for r in range(len(rooms[0])):
    for c in range(len(rooms[1])):
      rooms[r][c] = 0
  
  possibleNextRoom.clear()

def countRooms():

  roomCount = 0

  for r in range(len(rooms)):
    for c in range(len(rooms)):
      if rooms[r][c] == 1:
        roomCount += 1

  return roomCount

def findPossibleRooms():

  for r in range(len(rooms) - 1):
    for c in range(len(rooms) - 1):
      if rooms[r][c] == 1:
        if rooms[r][c+1] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r, c+1))
        if rooms[r][c-1] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r, c-1))
        if rooms[r-1][c] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r-1, c))
        if rooms[r+1][c] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r+1, c))

def addRoom():
  x = random.randrange(0, len(possibleNextRoom))

  rooms[possibleNextRoom[x][0]][possibleNextRoom[x][1]] = 1
  possibleNextRoom.pop(x)

def generateLevel():

  global x, possibleNextRoom

  startLevel()

  while countRooms() < maxRooms:
    countRooms()
    findPossibleRooms()
    addRoom()

def makeRoomsForLevel():

  counter = 1

  for r in range(len(rooms)):
    for c in range(len(rooms)):
      if rooms[c][r] == 1:
        world[f"room{counter}"] = Room(
          f"room{counter}",
          "",
          {},
          False,
          None,
          False,
          None,
          False,
          None,
          True,
          (r, c)
        )
        counter += 1

def findExits():
  counter = 1;

  for x in range(len(world)):
    if rooms[world[f"room{counter}"].coords[0]] + 1 == 1:
      pass

def fillRooms():
  counter = 1

  for x in range(len(world)):
    x = random.randrange(1, 2)

    if x == 1:
      world[f"room{counter}"].hasItem = True

    x = random.randrange(1, 10)

    if x == 1:
      world[f"room{counter}"].hasWeapon = True

    x = random.randrange(1, 4)

    if x == 1:
      world[f"room{counter}"].hasEnemy = True

    counter += 1
```

And here is the entire code:

```
import random
import numpy as np

world = {}

class Player():
  def __init__(self, health, maxHealth, baseDmg, dmg, name, weapons, items, isAlive, previousRoom, roomName):
    self.health = health
    self.maxHealth = maxHealth
    self.baseDmg = baseDmg
    self.dmg = dmg
    self.name = name
    self.weapons = weapons
    self.items = items
    self.isAlive = isAlive
    self.previousRoom = previousRoom
    self.room = world[roomName]

  def Move(self, direction):
    if direction not in self.room.exits:
      print("Cannot Move In That Direction!")
      return
    newRoomName = self.room.exits[direction]
    self.previousRoom = world[self.room.name]
    print("Moving to", newRoomName)
    self.room = world[newRoomName]

  def MoveBack(self):
    self.room = world[self.previousRoom.name]
    print("Moving to", self.room.name)

class Enemy():
  def __init__(self, health, dmg, hasLoot, lootItem, isAlive):
    self.health = health
    self.dmg = dmg
    self.hasLoot = hasLoot
    self.lootItem = lootItem
    self.isAlive = isAlive

class Weapon():
  def __init__(self, name, dmg, description):
    self.name = name
    self.dmg = dmg
    self.description = description

class Item():
  def __init__(self, name, amt, description):
    self.name = name
    self.amt = amt
    self.description = description

class Room():
  def __init__(self, name, description, exits, hasWeapon, weapon, hasItem, item, hasEnemy, enemy, isFirstVisit, coords):
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.exits = exits
    self.hasWeapon = hasWeapon
    self.weapon = weapon
    self.hasItem = hasItem
    self.item = item
    self.hasEnemy = hasEnemy
    self.enemy = enemy
    self.isFirstVisit = isFirstVisit
    self.coords = coords

#######################Dungeon Generation###################
rooms = np.zeros((11, 11))
maxRooms = 7
possibleNextRoom = []

def startLevel():
  for r in range(len(rooms[0])):
    for c in range(len(rooms[1])):
      rooms[r][c] = 0

  possibleNextRoom.clear()

  halfHeight = int(len(rooms[1]) / 2)
  halfWidth = int(len(rooms[0]) / 2)
  rooms[halfWidth][halfHeight] = 1

def resetLevel():
  for r in range(len(rooms[0])):
    for c in range(len(rooms[1])):
      rooms[r][c] = 0
  
  possibleNextRoom.clear()

def countRooms():

  roomCount = 0

  for r in range(len(rooms)):
    for c in range(len(rooms)):
      if rooms[r][c] == 1:
        roomCount += 1

  return roomCount

def findPossibleRooms():

  for r in range(len(rooms) - 1):
    for c in range(len(rooms) - 1):
      if rooms[r][c] == 1:
        if rooms[r][c+1] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r, c+1))
        if rooms[r][c-1] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r, c-1))
        if rooms[r-1][c] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r-1, c))
        if rooms[r+1][c] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r+1, c))

def addRoom():
  x = random.randrange(0, len(possibleNextRoom))

  rooms[possibleNextRoom[x][0]][possibleNextRoom[x][1]] = 1
  possibleNextRoom.pop(x)

def generateLevel():

  global x, possibleNextRoom

  startLevel()

  while countRooms() < maxRooms:
    countRooms()
    findPossibleRooms()
    addRoom()

def makeRoomsForLevel():

  counter = 1

  for r in range(len(rooms)):
    for c in range(len(rooms)):
      if rooms[c][r] == 1:
        world[f"room{counter}"] = Room(
          f"room{counter}",
          "",
          {},
          False,
          None,
          False,
          None,
          False,
          None,
          True,
          (r, c)
        )
        counter += 1

def findExits():
  counter = 1;

  for x in range(len(world)):
    if rooms[world[f"room{counter}"].coords[0]] + 1 == 1:
      pass

def fillRooms():
  counter = 1

  for x in range(len(world)):
    x = random.randrange(1, 2)

    if x == 1:
      world[f"room{counter}"].hasItem = True

    x = random.randrange(1, 10)

    if x == 1:
      world[f"room{counter}"].hasWeapon = True

    x = random.randrange(1, 4)

    if x == 1:
      world[f"room{counter}"].hasEnemy = True

    counter += 1
############################################################

generateLevel()
makeRoomsForLevel()
findExits()

WoodenSword = Weapon("Wooden Sword", 5, "A wooden sword. Looks like a kid's toy.")
IronDagger = Weapon("Iron Dagger", 8, "Small, sharp, and pointy. Good for fighting monsters!")

HealthPot = Item("Health Potion", 1, "A Potion of Instant Health. Restores 10 Health.")

goblin1 = Enemy(25, 2, True, [HealthPot, IronDagger], True)

player = Player(10, 10, 5, 5, "", [], [], True, "room1", "room1")

def ShowInv():
  print("*******************************")
  print("Name:", player.name)
  print("Health:", player.health)
  print("Weapons:")
  for i in player.weapons:
    print(" ===============================")
    print(" Weapon:", i.name)
    print(" Description:", i.description)
    print(" Damage:", i.dmg)
    print(" ===============================")
  print("Items:")
  for i in player.items:
    print(" ===============================")
    print(" Item:", i.name)
    print(" Amount:", i.amt)
    print(" Description:", i.description)
    print(" ===============================")
  print("*******************************")

def testItems(item):
  exists = item in player.items
  return exists

def fight(enemy):
  print("Your Health:", player.health)
  print("Enemy Health:", enemy.health)

  ans = input("What would you like to do?\n>>")
  if ans == "attack":
    chance = random.randrange(1, 20)
    if chance >= 10:
      enemy.health -= player.dmg
    else:
      print("You did not roll high enough...\nYour turn has been passed...")

  if ans == "heal":
    chance = random.randrange(1, 20)
    if testItems(HealthPot):
      if chance >= 10:
        x = 0
        for item in player.items:
          if item == HealthPot:
            player.health += 10
            if player.health > player.maxHealth:
              player.health = player.maxHealth
            item.amt -= 1
            if item.amt <= 0:
              player.items.pop(x)
              break
          x += 1
      else:
        print("You did not roll high enough...\nYour turn has been passed...")

  if ans == "run":
    chance = random.randrange(1, 20)
    if chance >= 10:
      player.MoveBack()
    else:
      print("You did not roll high enough...\nYour turn has been passed...")

  if enemy.health > 0 and player.health > 0:
    chance  = random.randrange(1, 20)
    if chance >= 10:
      player.health -= enemy.dmg
  else:
    if enemy.health <= 0:
      enemy.isAvile = False;

def testRoom():
  if player.room.hasWeapon:
    if player.room.isFirstVisit:
      player.weapons.append(player.room.weapon)
  
  if player.room.hasItem:
    if player.room.isFirstVisit:
      player.items.append(player.room.item)

  if player.room.hasEnemy:
    if player.room.isFirstVisit:
      while player.room.enemy.health > 0:
        fight(player.room.enemy)

  player.room.isFirstVisit = False


while True:
  command = input(">>")

  if command in {"N", "S", "E", "W"}:
    player.Move(command)
    testRoom()

  elif command == "look":
    print(player.room.description)
    print("Exits:", *','.join(list(player.room.exits.keys())))

  elif command == "inv":
    ShowInv()

  elif command == "heal":
    if testItems(HealthPot):
      player.health += 10
      if player.health > player.maxHealth:
        player.health = player.maxHealth
    else:
      print("You don't have any", HealthPot.name, "\bs")

  else:
    print("Invalid Command")
```

Comment: Do you need `rooms[world[f"room{counter}"].coords[0]]`? (i.e. move the `]` to the end)

Comment: rooms is the 2d array that stores all the values that arent 0 in the array, i will ifx my question to include it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in `findExits`? You set counter to 1 and never increment it. Are you sure you didn't mean to use x? Also you should be passing two indices to rooms (like `rooms[1,1]`), you only pass `coords[0]` which will return an entire row

Comment: im trying to see if there is a room next to the current room i am working with, and if there is, append the associated exits to the exit dictianary in the current room object.

Comment: Do you need to check all 4 directions (up, down, right, left) for a 1? (1 implies there is a room, is that counted as an exit?)

Comment: yes. the pass in the if statement was going to be a nested if for all the directions.

Comment: a full exit dictionary will look like this: {"N": "a", "S": "b", "E": "c", "W": "d"} where a, b, c, and d are the names of the rooms in that direction (N being up, S being down, E being right, and W being left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need something like:

```
#find the name of the room given the coordinates
def findRoom(x, y):
    for i in range(len(world)):
        if world[f"room{i+1}"].coords == (x, y):
            return f"room{i+1}"
    return None

def findExits():
    for i in range(len(world)):
        x, y = world[f"room{i+1}"].coords
        exits = dict()
        
        #east
        if rooms[x, y+1] == 1:
            exits["E"] = findRoom(x, y+1)
        
        #south
        if rooms[x+1, y] == 1:
            exits["S"] = findRoom(x+1, y)
        
        #west
        if rooms[x, y-1] == 1:
            exits["W"] = findRoom(x, y-1)
        
        #north
        if rooms[x-1, y] == 1:
            exits["N"] = findRoom(x-1, y)
            
        world[f"room{i+1}"].exits = exits
```

After running the above, the exits for `room1` look like:

```
>>> world["room1"].exits
{'E': 'room2', 'S': 'room4'}
```

You can work with the above structure, changing the keys and values as needed.

Comment: Actually, I have another error with this... it works fine, but sometimes it says i can move in a direction, but when i move it give me a keyerror for none

Comment: Have you tried running the entire program and moving around?

Comment: @JedidiahBlitz - The room is probably on the edge of the map. You need to check if x and y are within the dimensions of rooms.